# retrieve distinct recent records with group in rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-4

H,

I have a table where I am trying to get the latest 3 transactions. The table has 2 amount fields and i need to display largest of 3 by looking both amount fields. 
Scenario1: If the 2 records have same amount, then I should get only one record which is recent.

I have the working query, but the issue is I am not getting the recent record in case of same amount field, instead I am getting the old record.

```
Transactions
id    expense_amt   income_amt    transaction_type
1     100           NULL           1
2     200           NULL           3
3     NULL          400            1
4     NULL          800            2
5     1000          NULL           1
```

So the output of largest 3 would be records of [1000, 800, 400]
The below is my rails query

```
Model.select("(COALESCE(expense_amt, 0) + COALESCE(income_amt, 0)) AS combined_amt, id, transaction_type")
.group("combined_amt")
.order("combined_amt DESC")
.limit(3)
.map{|row| row["combined_amt"]}
end
```

But this query returned the largest of 3 with old record. I tried 
.max('id') before .group(). But it didnt work.

Any inputs/suggestions would be appreciated